# "sourceMaps is null" in Firefox Developer Edition

Tags: firefox, source-maps

In the debugging window of the developer console - I can see all my javascript resources listed, but in of them it just says `sourceMaps is null`.

The resources I'm trying to fetch are some minified jquery, and unminified, but consolidated javascript. The javascript does not contain a sourcemaps comment.

Any suggestions for how I'd resolve this?

Comment: Same problem here with developer edition. I can't see any files in the debugger, just the message "sourceMap is null". There was no mistake before, suddenly this started. I tried the standard version (57.0b7) and nigthly (58.0a1) and it works well.

Comment: I'm seeing this too, after disabling source maps in the DevTools settings.

Comment: Tanks @NickZalutskiy, you are right. I didn't expect this option to be disabled.

Comment: Glad it helped. For posterity, here is the [bug 1410590](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1410590) The issue resolved itself for me, but I've seen it show up once again.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. I resolved it by updating the about:config settings

Open about:config

Search for devtools.source-map.client-service.enabled

The value of this option should be true. 
[image]